# Can AutoMapper map object to model property of the same type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I am attempting to improve my data flow between my MVC 3 Model and Views (mainly CRUD). I have taken the approach of using ViewModels and FormModels. My ViewModel contains everything it need to represent the view FormData, DropDownLists etc. The FormModel simply contains the FormData fields that are submitted by the form and are needed to update a record.

My question is can I use AutoMapper to map UserDto information onto my FormData field in my ViewModel?

Obviously my mapping below is only mapping between the two object and not an object to property but I have tried using the ‘.ForMember’ mapping options but they are again for object members not an object to an object member. I have also looked at Custom Type Convertors but not sure if this is the right way to go.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserDto, UserViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<UserViewModel, UserDto>();

public class UserViewModel
{
    public User FormData { get; set; }

    // DropDownLists

    // Other view specific data

}

public class UserFormModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Age { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you got any error? What is the exact issue?

Comment: When I verify AutoMapper config is valid with Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); it tells me the FormData field is not mapped and I need to Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, or rename the property which I know. I just need to understand how I do the mapping if its at all possible. If not do I then just manually map?

Comment: Yes, for each type, you need to put a mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the map to the FormData property type and then tell AutoMapper to use this map.

(The following will likely not compile; I'm in the process of recreating my work machine and am working from memory).

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserDto, User>(); // set up property mapping

Mapper.CreateMap<UserDto, UserViewModel>()
.ForMember(vm => vm.FormData, map => map.MapFrom(dto => Mapper.Map<UserDto, User>(dto)));
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer but still not working. Still saying non of the properties are mapped and that i need to undertake custom mapping. Spent to long on this now so may just do it manually anyhow!

Comment: Actually came back to it and got it working with the exact code supplied. Only typo was that I used .ForMember and not .ForProperty. Many thanks.